# webdav: adding office 365 location doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to add a documentlibrary from office 365 sharepoint in my MS Server 2008 R2 as `networklocation`, but it tells me it is an invalid networklocation (which it isn't as I can enter it in windows 7 without any problem on multiple computers)

How can I fix this error so I can add the networklocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that I needed to install this feature: "**Desktop Experience**"

Issue solved.